STATUS_MAPPED_ALIGNMENT error when using NtMapViewOfSection
Im trying to use NtMapViewOfSection to remap a section but everytime i use the function it gives me the error STATUS_MAPPED_ALIGNMENT 0xC0000220.
If i replace the viewBase with a nullptr and it works.
my cpp code
HANDLE hSection = NULL;
LARGE_INTEGER sectionMaxSize = {};
sectionMaxSize.QuadPart = 0x1000;

NTSTATUS status = NtCreateSection(&hSection, SECTION_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &sectionMaxSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, SEC_COMMIT, NULL);
status = NtUnmapViewOfSection(hProc, address);


PVOID viewBase = address; 

LARGE_INTEGER SectionOffset = {};
SIZE_T ViewSize = 0;

status = NtMapViewOfSection(hSection, hProc, &viewBase, 0, 0x1000, &SectionOffset, &ViewSize, ViewUnmap, 0, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

address is just a PVOID
i think it might be because im unmapping the view before but im not really sure

Given that the error code is STATUS_MAPPED_ALIGNMENT, have you considered the possibility that the address is not properly aligned?

The microsoft website says it gets rounded down automatically "the view is allocated starting at the specified virtual address rounded down to the next 64-kilobyte address boundary."

NtMapViewOfSection is not a documented API. The corresponding documented API is MapViewOfFile which requires alignment: " This must be a multiple of the system's memory allocation granularity, or the function fails."

address this is wahat value ?

STATUS_MAPPED_ALIGNMENT was when ViewBase or SectionOffset incorrect aligned. in your case SectionOffset  is 0 (ok) so error in ViewBase (address) value

this is exactly place Status = STATUS_MAPPED_ALIGNMENT; where you fail

@RaymondChen I meant ZwMapViewOfSection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nf-wdm-zwmapviewofsection

@RbMm The address is just a function address i got from GetProcAddress on ntdll. I checked the link you sent me and added error detection for the address and section offset but it output anything for both of them.

Of course in this case ( function address) this is error value. So unclear what you want. You got what must got. And what you really try todo ?

ZwMapViewOfSection is for kernel mode WDM drivers. But you're calling it from user mode, so the documentation does not apply as written. At the bottom of the documentation, click the link Using Nt and Zw Versions of the Native System Services Routines and it will explain that the Nt versions are not the same as the Zw versions. The Nt versions apply stricter parameter validation.

@RaymondChen - Nt versions are not the same as the Zw versions - only when we call this from kernel mode (from ntoskrnl.exe ). and previous mode make different. when we call this from user mode (from ntdll.dll ) - the Nt and Zw is absolute the same function (have the same address)

Even though the Zw and Nt versions are the same function, they behave differently based on the prior mode. The documentation for the Zw functions is from the point of view of a kernel caller. The code in this question is not a kernel caller.

Of course this is from user mode and ntdll, so this link unrelated here. Additional checks pointers/copy user buffer when api called from user mode here unrelated too. In any previous mode BaseAddress is checked for 64kb alignment, and if not STATUS_MAPPED_ALIGNED returned
